# Fasting more than 3 days

Tags: fasting

Angirasa first says

> As regards Brahmanas and Kshatriyas, fasts for three nights at a stretch are ordained for them. Indeed, O chief of men, **a fast for one night, for two nights, and for three nights, may be observed by them**. (They should never go beyond three nights).

Then

> That man who passes a whole year observing fasts for **five days and taking food on only the sixth day**, acquires the merit of the Horse-sacrifice.

Then again...

> No fast for **more than a month** has been ordained. Even this is the ordinance in respect of fasts that has been declared by sages conversant with duties.

So, is it allowed to fast more than 3 days together?

[Source](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/mbs/mbs13109.htm)

Comment: It is for gruhastas.